# Trying to run pyexiv2

Tags: python, pyexiv2

I'm trying to run a simple code to test that I have installed correctly pyexiv2 in my computer. I'm using python 2.6.6. on windows 7 64 bit

So I run this simple code:

```
import pyexiv2
print pyexiv2.exiv2_version_info
```

and I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Usuario/Desktop/pyexiv2/pyexiv2.py", line 1, in <module>
import pyexiv2
File "C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\pyexiv2\pyexiv2.py", line 3, in <module>
print pyexiv2.version_info
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'version_info'
```

How can I fix that? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You named your own file `pyexiv2.py` as well; rename it or delete it, as it is being imported instead of the installed module.